# vb.net [Panel].Select() on onMouseEnter to scroll even if panel not focused; this doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, scroll, panel, mouseenter

Here is a custom menu I've made, called `MenuM` (a user control class; see picture below), consisting of 2 panels: `MenuM_Caption` and `MenuMItems_Container`. Each `MenuMItem` is also a user control within `MenuMItems_Container` panel.

[image: Custom Menu]

To be able to scrool my menu (the `MenuMItems_Container` panel) I have to select any `MenuMItem`, otherwise the panel `MenuMItems_Container` simply doesn't scroll, even when writing one of following commands (or both):

1) Within main form containing an instance of `MenuM` as control:

```
Public Partial Class MyForm 'System.Windows.Forms.Form
   Private Sub MenuM1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuM1.MouseEnter
      Me.MenuM1.Select()
   End Sub
End Class
```

2) And/or within `MenuM` class

```
Public Class MenuM
   Private Sub MenuMItems_Container_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuMItems_Container.MouseEnter
      Me.MenuMItems_Container.Select()
   End Sub
End Class
```

The handler doesn't enter `MenuMItems_Container.MouseEnter` event. I think the reason is because the `MenuMItem` classes raise the event before their container can handle/raise the same event.

Does anybody know what to do to solve this issue, please? (`Me.Parent.Select()` on `OnMouseEnter()` within `MenuMItem` Class?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

Within Class `MenuM`:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnGotFocus(e As System.EventArgs)
   MyBase.OnGotFocus(e)
   Me.MenuMItems_Container.Select()
End Sub

Private Sub MenuMItems_Container_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuMItems_Container.MouseEnter
   Me.MenuMItems_Container.Select() 'if no MenuMItems or less then MenuMItems_Container Height
End Sub

Private Sub MenuM_Caption_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuM_Caption.MouseEnter
   Me.MenuMItems_Container.Select()
End Sub
```

And within Class `MenuMItem`

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseEnter(e As System.EventArgs)
   MyBase.OnMouseEnter(e)
   Me.Parent.Select()
End Sub
```